# Connecting graphical representations to an enum Java

Tags: java, list, graphics, enums, representation

I am currently stuck in connecting a graphical representation to an enum in Java.
My current enum is looking like

```
public enum TypesOfCarriage {
    PERSONCARRIAGE, GOODCARRIAGE, SPEICALCARRIAGE
}
```

And now I've got graphical representations of those "PERSONCARRIAGE, GOODCARRIAGE, SPEICALCARRIAGE" in a txt file. 
A personcarriage would i.e. look like this: shown in the link

[image]

Firstly: how ist possible to print out this graphical representation

Secondly: can I link this representation to my enum?

Comment: One way to link:  use a `Map`, here an `EnumMap`

Comment: How can I link this to an enumMap?

Comment: Are you familiar with the general topic of how to create and use Maps, how they work and such? If not, then this is where you should start. If you are, then you will want to make the question above more specific.

Comment: I have read now the articles about the EnumMap, but I am still not finding out how to implement the graphical representation to my object or to the enum... Do you've got an idea?